# Word tracking does not show authors of edits

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

My documents in Word 2007, of any age, have recently stopped showing the authorship of edits added in tracking mode.  I can change colors of tracking edits, but when I put the cursor over the edit, mine or someone eles's, the authorship bubble I am accustomed to seeing no longer appears.  Any idea how to fix this?  We had a recent office update and these symptoms kicked in after this update occured.

Answer (score 0):

#### When I put the cursor over an edit, the ScreenTip no longer appears.

> Wwhen I put the cursor over the edit, mine or someone eles's, the authorship bubble I am accustomed to seeing no longer appears.

The "authorship bubbles" are called **ScreenTips**.

To enable **ScreenTips** you need to turn on `Show All Revisions Inline` (inline comments can be viewed when you rest your pointer on the comment indicator.):

> 1. Click the Review tab.
> 2. Click the Balloons button.
> 3. Then select the option you want:
>
>    - Show Revisions in Balloons,
>    - **Show All Revisions Inline**,
>    - Show Only Comments and Formatting in Balloons.

[image]

Source [Use Balloons or Reviewing Pane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Microsoft-Office-Word-2007/0220__Collaboration/UseBalloonsorReviewingPane.htm)